# Why does submit button have a Webresources.axd?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a very basic submit button without a postbackurl specified but it creates a webresources.axd reference.  I did see [Why is my ASP.NET page injecting this WebResource.axd Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256430/why-is-my-asp-net-page-injecting-this-webresource-axd-javascript-file) but I don't have postbackurl in the statement.

```
<form method="post" action="/thispage" id="formAlpha">
<asp:button ID="cmdSubmit"  text="Submit" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Remove the button, there's no axd.  Is there something else that could be causing it?  I don't use JQuery.

Comment: Do any other control in your page have postbackurl property?

Comment: Search for this string `WebResource` in your project. Somewhere embeded resource getting used and you get it.

Comment: Would seem I need to add CausesValidation="false" to stop the WebResource.axd from being added.  Thanks for the suggestions tho.